# Overpowered Death Trap?

Tags: borderlands-2

My friends (people I know well and see at school) and I were playing some Borderlands 2, and we decided to go battle Master Gee the Invincible. Upon starting the battle, I summoned Death Trap, and he shot a lightning bolt which dealt 8999999K DMG per 1/5 second even after he died. We tried it again, and the same thing happened.

Also, where Death Traps level is, it said 22201 instead of my 72.

Is this a glitch and if so, what would have caused it to happen?

Comment: What is the actual question :D ?

Comment: Levels of "over 9000" are fairly easy to mod, and people are often advertising getting "legit" items and resources using modded game clients. Who was the host of your game, and are you sure this person won't use a hacked client?

Comment: @OrcJMR He says he is the one who summoned death trap and was with friends. I'd think if one of them was using a modded client they would let the rest know that they were.

Comment: @Katustrawfic "A friend" can very well mean "a person you don't know and I don't wanna tell about", and even real friends pull off pranks on each other, so it does not hurt to investigate. Apart from that, I am not aware of anything but a modded client that can cause such behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This glitch is usually caused by a modded game client being used in your game that affects weapon stats: dmg, spread, bullets, etc. The problem isn't ever really fixed even if the actual level goes back to normal. The damage and stats of Death Trap will be messed up permanently. I've actually been testing this myself trying to fix after it happened to me

Comment: someone actually did say that in a comment....